# Javascript show validation message right after the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate a form using javascript. On button click function I have called a javascript function where I have displayed the message after the text box. The number of times I click the button same number of times message gets displayed just below the existing validation message.  Please help me 
Here goes my code:

```
function check() {
        var v = true;
        if ((document.getElementById('firstname').value == "")) {

            $('#firstname').after('Validation message');
            document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor='#DA394B';

            v = false; 

        } 
        if ((document.getElementById('lastname').value == "")) {
            $('#lastname').after('Some validation text');
            document.getElementById('lastname').style.borderColor = '#DA394B';

            v = false;
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what v is for. Which i probably don't because v (I hate one letter variable names...).

Try this:

```
function check() {
        var v = true;
        if ((document.getElementById('firstname').value == "")) {

            if ($('#firstnameMessage').length <= 0)
            {
                $('#firstname').after('<p id="firstnameMessage">Validation message</p>');
                document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor='#DA394B';
            }

            v = false; 
        } 

        if ((document.getElementById('lastname').value == "")) {
            if ($('#lastnameMessage').length <= 0)
            {
                $('#lastname').after('<p id="lastnameMessage">Some validation text</p>');
                document.getElementById('lastname').style.borderColor = '#DA394B';
            }

            v = false;
        }
        return v;
}
```

Simple fiddle to show this working: https://jsfiddle.net/srLt7wo0/

Comment: I am so sorry, actually I must have written  'isvalid' instead of only 'v'. thanks for the answer i will try and please think on this some more

Comment: still the same problem . some validation text is displayed more than once

Comment: @nwemember I updated my answer. And single letter variables are perfectly acceptable. I just don't care for them

Answer (score 0):

Using .after will insert another element per http://api.jquery.com/after/
The below solution uses a separate element already in the HTML to display the error message. If you use .after you have to check that you have not already added an element to your HTML

HTML

```
<input id="firstname" type="text"/><div id="firstnameMessage"></div>
<input id="lastname" type="text"/><div id="lastnameMessage"></div>
```

JS

```
function check() {
    $("#firstnameMessage,#lastnameMessage").text(''); // clear message, reset border color
    document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor='';
    document.getElementById('lastname').style.borderColor='';

    var isValid = true;
    if ((document.getElementById('firstname').value == "")) {

        $('#firstnameMessage').text('First name is required');
        document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor='#DA394B';

        isValid = false;
    }

    if ((document.getElementById('lastname').value == "")) {
        $('#lastnameMessage').text('Last name is required');
        document.getElementById('lastname').style.borderColor='#DA394B';

        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: This may be better. It will remove the message and styling after the user enters information into the input and checks it again.

Comment: Both solutions work, he can handle clearing the messages elsewhere. The bigger issue was that he was using .after without knowing what effect it has.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood you issue but maybe this could help you :)

```js
window.firstname = document.getElementById('firstname')
window.lastname = document.getElementById('lastname')
window.issue = document.getElementById('issue')

function check() {
  
  if(firstname.value == '' || lastname.value == '') {
    issue.innerHTML = 'Please, use correct credentials.'
  } else {
    issue.innerHTML = ''
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input id="firstname" />
<input id="lastname" />

<button onclick="check()">
Check
</button>

<div id="issue" style="color:red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if i understand you.

It will add only one message no matter how many times you click

```
function check() {
    var v = true;
    if ((document.getElementById('firstname').value == "")) {

        $('#message').remove()
        $('#firstname').after('<span id='message'>Validation message</span>');
        document.getElementById('firstname').style.borderColor='#DA394B';

        v = false; 

    } 
    if ((document.getElementById('lastname').value == "")) {

        $('#message').remove()
        $('#lastname').after('<span id='message'>Some validation text</span>');
        document.getElementById('lastname').style.borderColor = '#DA394B';

        v = false;
    }
    return v;
}
```